# Crop animated gifs

Tags: image-editing

Is there any free program to crop animated gifs? With GUI, because ImageMagick can do that pretty easily, but I have quite a few different gifs and preset coordinates for batch cropping is a no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut, and not the most Apple-like experience you'll ever have, but [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) can definitely do this.

http://gimpforums.com/thread-is-cropping-animated-gifs-possible

Comment: thank you, good old free gimp works, despite fugly interface, I've forgot about it. :)